# Sitecore ASP.NET - manage aliases per domain

Tags: sitecore, alias

I have site running Sitecore 6.3. This site include some subsites (for example www.a.com & www.b.com). I want to ask: is it possible to create separate aliases for this sites (e.g. www.a.com/alias & www.b.com/alias should redirect to different pages). Now if create an alias for site www.a.com it will be also in www.b.com. Any ideas how to manage this? 
Thnx.

Comment: There is by default no way of doing this in Sitecore. I would presume that this functionality could be made, but I don't know where to start. Maybe try asking Sitecore at https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/Default.aspx (requires access, which you should get if you've had Sitecore training)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible. I have already made a Sitecore support ticket for this. I have also worked this out and for me their solution worked fine. (haven't implemented it on the live website yet, because we had no agreement on the costs yet). This is some sample code you might want to look at:

```
   class MultiSiteAliasResolver : AliasResolver
{
    public new void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

        if (!Settings.AliasesActive)
        {
            Tracer.Warning("Aliases are not active.");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Database database = Sitecore.Context.Database;
            if (database == null)
            {
                Tracer.Warning("There is no context database in AliasResover.");
            }

            Item aliasItem = getAliasItem(args);
            if (aliasItem != null)
            {
                LinkField linkField = aliasItem.Fields["Linked item"];
                if (linkField != null)
                {
                    Item AliasLinkedTo = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(linkField.TargetID);

                    if (AliasLinkedTo != null)
                    {
                        Sitecore.Context.Item = AliasLinkedTo;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Process(args);
                }
            }
        }            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the alias item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The args.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Item getAliasItem(HttpRequestArgs args) 
    {
        string websitePath = Sitecore.Context.Site.RootPath.ToLower();

        if (args.LocalPath.Length > 1)
        {
            Item aliasItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(websitePath + "/settings/aliassen/" + args.LocalPath);

            if (aliasItem != null)
            {
                return aliasItem;
            }                
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This class could be inserted in the web.config in place of the AliasResolver. For example:

```
<processor type="CommandTemplates.Classes.MultiSiteAliasResolver, CommandTemplates" />
```

I hope this will work for you, good luck!

update: In my example I have a folder under each website node "/settings/aliassen/", that's the location I want the users to set alliases. By the way, also notice that when you change the AliasResolver like this the window that the standard Sitecore Alias button triggers won't have the needed functionality anymore. I haven't had any time to dins a way to make that work, however you could always explain the content managers how to work with your new solution.

Comment: This has been released as a module you can download from http://marketplace.sitecore.net -> Multisite alias resolver